# Не индексируются страницы с ЧПУ

Tags: seo, чпу

У меня на сайте статьи хранятся в базе, при выводе я меняю *url*,что бы не было `id?=..`  на */nazvanie_statyu_latinicoy*

Заметил,что они вроде нормально находились в гугле и яндексе,а теперь не найти никак,подскажите с чем это может быть связано?

В **sitemap** добавлял в таком виде `site.com/nazvanie_statyu_latinicoy`.

Comment: не пробовали в яндекс написать? а также не пробовали посмотреть, что "говорит" панель вебмастера по данным url?

Comment: яндекс вебмастер говорит,что статус "обрабатывается"

Comment: если вы комментарием выше имеете ввиду, что Вы запрашиваете информацию о странице, то: *В процессе сбора информации о странице отчет имеет статус «обрабатывается». Сбор и обработка информации производится в течение 1-2 минут. Как только обработка данных завершится, статус отчета изменится на «готово».*

Comment: Пишет "В данный момент адрес страницы неизвестен роботу." Дает совет добавить в sitemap,но она там есть,нужно ли в sitemap записывать страницу без ЧПУ?

Comment: да нет чпу нормально обрабатываются роботом. м.б. просто ссылки выполи из индекса. Возможно Вам стоит написать в тп яндекса по данному моменту.